# How to access the interior of gltf-model object3D.children.material in AFrame

Tags: aframe

I'm loading a gltf-model into aframe and some materials on some objects need adjusting. I am attempting to isolate and manipulate them by directly accessing the object3D property of the entity that contains the gltf component. The part of the object3D tree that I need to access is the .children Array. When I log that part to the console, it is an empty array, but I can twirl it down in the console and see the object properties I need. How do I access this in my script? the .children property is returning an empty array.

You can see my project here:
http://www.sensorium.love/experiments/yamashiro/walkthroughlit2/bonsaiLightsTest.html
The small black rectangle with the flare texture on it is one of many planes from the gltf. The large flare in the background is a primitive I made in aframe with the material as I would like it to be. I attempted to assign this to another plane object in my gltf, and it did not render. It should be applied to the child. 
If you inspect the console, you can see where I've logged this children array. It is an empty array, and yet if you twirl down the arrow next to it, you can see the underlying data I'm trying to access. But I can't understand how to access that in my script.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('flareplanes',{
            init:function(){
                let l1 = document.querySelector('#lta1');
                let lm3D1 = l1.object3D;
                console.log(lm3D1);
                let lmc = lm3D1.children;
                console.log(lmc);               
                for(let propName in lmc){
                    console.log(lmc[propName]);
                }
            }
        }); 

<a-scene>
<a-assets>
   <a-asset-item id="bonsailights" src="BonsaiLights.glb" ></a-asset-item>
   <img id="flare" src="assets/ledFlare.png"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>             

<a-entity id="lta1" gltf-part="src: #bonsailights; 
   part:BonsaiBendDLeafLiteL_01"></a-entity> 
<a-entity id="lta2" gltf-part="src: #bonsailights; part:BonsaiBendDLeafLiteL_02" material="src: #flare; shader: flat; opacity: 0.99; blending: additive"></a-entity>

<a-entity id="plane" geometry="primitive: plane" position="1.0 1.6 2" rotation="0 180 0" material="src: #flare; shader: flat; opacity: 0.99; blending: additive" flareplanes></a-entity> 

</a-scene>


let lmc = lm3D1.children;
console.log(lmc); // Array empty
console.log(lmc[0]); //undefined
```

// yet, in the console, twirling the arrow reveals the object I need to //access. It appears that this object is entry 0 in the array, but accessing //directly fails. How do I access this object in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try iterating through the mesh children, not the object3Ds:

```
var mesh = el.getObject3D('mesh');
mesh.traverse(node => {
  if (node.isMesh) {
      console.log(node.material) 
  }
});
```

[Here's](https://glitch.com/~aframe-model-opacity) a glitch in which I access child materials to manipulate the opacity.

---

If the `el.getObject3D('mesh')` is null, try waiting for the `model-loaded` event:

```
handleModel: function() {
   let mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh')
   if (!mesh) {
       this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', this.handleModel.bind(this)
       return
   }
   // the model should be loaded by this point 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sure your answer is correct, as it works in the glitch example you provided (thanks for going the extra mile with the example! brilliant~ Unfortunately, the getObject3D('mesh') command is returning undefined for me.  http://www.sensorium.love/experiments/yamashiro/walkthroughlit2/bonsaiLightsTest.html

Comment: Make sure you’re accessing the mesh after the model has loaded. Listen to the `model-loaded` event. https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/gltf-model.html#events_model_loaded

Comment: thank you Diego. That solved the problem. Now working great!

Comment: @ThomasWilliams I forgot it could be an issue, I've updated the anwser :)

Comment: Thanks Piotr. Your example project was super helpful. I added it to the Aframe slack channel #beginnerdemos. you rock!~

Comment: @ThomasWilliams thank you very much :) I'll try and comment it a bit when i have some time